# How can I make PowerShell perform a MS EXCEL "Save As CSV(MS-DOS)" programmatically?

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a file that says it is in CSV format.

When I try to load the file into our ETL software,
the software complains that it is not properly formatted.

My manual workaround has been to load the file into MS-Excel and
do a File--> Save As--> CSV (MS-DOS).
Once this is done, the file loads properly.

I have many files weekly that require this manual step.
How could I automate this Excel "Save as" in PowerShell
and insure it applies the CSV(MS-DOS) Format?

The first image is the raw file.
The second image is the file after saving in Excel

[image: Bad]

[image: Good]

Comment: Of course this is possile, this is a core feature of powershell, but its really hard to say whats the issue without further details of the file itself.

Comment: I considered adding before and after files, but i will need to redact data out of them. Plus they are each about 5 MB in size. I know for certain that whatever the MS-Excel "Save As" works when I select CSV(MS-DOS) for file format. How would I emulate that in Powershell?

Comment: Please add the first 3 or 4 lines of such a CSV file in the question. Open in in Notepad and copy/paste. Perhaps it is just a question of your ETL software not understanding the field delimiter character in there

Comment: Does the PowerShell cmdlet `Import-Csv` successfully load the file? What is your ETL software? Ab Initio, DataStage, SAS, ...?

Comment: ETL software is iDashboards   I can send a screen capture of the good and bad I do notice that in the good sample (After Excel's SaveAs  CSV (MS-DOS) there are a lot of commas on some lines . Could that be the issue? And if so.. how does one do that from a command line.?

Comment: Please check the official document to encode to ms-dos format https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-5.1